# Which logging library contains class Log with static methods?

Tags: java, logging

With which library following code will work?

```
Log.info("Task available: " + task.getName());
```

It's from some example where author dropped imports.

Comment: I would propose to use `slf4j` with a binding do you prefer (log4j, logback, ...) create a logger e.g. `Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("foobar");` and refactor the code.

Comment: For a quick example-test, just comment it out.

Comment: @xerx593 I am reading the question like "I have a source code which is not executable". In that sense, your comment isn't helpful.

Comment: If your question is "how do I get these examples to work"; just writing a class Log that has these methods (and prints to stdout) might be the easiest solution. Eclipse will even offer you to create the missing class with all methods that are used.

Comment: I know how to log with several libs, but I'm curious about where does exact this "Log.info" class defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This look suspiciously like [TinyLog](http://www.tinylog.org/) (unless you care for the `Log` instead of `Logger`). And it just reached 1.0, btw.

Comment: Yeah, seams pretty much similar

Answer (score 1):

To make this (logging)line work, I recommend to:

1. Downlad/install/make available on the class path: [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/).jar (maven coordinates: log4j:log4j)
2. In each class (MyClass), where Log is accessed/occurs, you need to:

   ```
   // import! ...
   import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
   class MyClass {

      ...
      // ...and declare/make it accesible as a object/class variable:
      private static final Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
      ...
   }
   ```

Comment: You saying it's not the class, but capitalized variable?